# Jquery mobile data-position="fixed" doesn't work for data-role="header"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My header should be on top when I scroll page but it stays on top or disappear. Can you help ? Thank you very much.

Webstie: [site](http://testing.ats-global.com)

HTML:

```
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" >
 ...content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-header{
    background: #2E4F80 url('/css/mobile-header-bg.jpg') no-repeat !important;
}
#header .ui-btn{width: 37px !important; height: 37px !important;}
```

Comment: It shows when i scroll on top only if I click or double click on page.

Comment: What is the solution u gave.?

Comment: The obvious solution would be data-tap-toggle="false";